# put all my beans in different file

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

I am using spring mvc and spring security. In my security-app-context.xml I have:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="MyUserDetailsService"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

And therefore I need to configure `MyUserDetailsService` in this security-app-context.xml file. So I added:

```
<beans:bean id="MyUserDetailsService"
            class="my.web.authentication.GreenWheelsUserDetailsService">
    <beans:property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <beans:property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
</beans:bean>
```

But this cause me to add `transactionManager` and `userDao` beans to this file too! So I added:

```
<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="my.dataAccess.hibernate.HibernateTransactionManager"/>
    <beans:bean id="userDao" class="my.dataAccess.hibernate.HibernateUserDao"/>
```

But now I want to add anothr beans for other DAOs. I prefer to put all my beans in different file then the security-app-context.xml file. How do I do that and keep the `authentication-manager` section correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use import:

```
<beans:import resource="beans.xml" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spring <beans:import resource="someotherfile.xml" /> to import any file into your spring security file.